# How to deal with optional parameters in browser API when using TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Example:

The [Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) constructor (`new Error([message[, fileName[, lineNumber]]])`) has two optional parameters (fileName and lineNumber) that I would like to use but the TypeScript compiler complains with the following error message `Expected 0-1 arguments, but got 3`.

What is the proper way to prevent this kind of error in TypeScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [`Error` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) you linked above, I see this:

- `message`: Optional. A human-readable description of the error.
- `fileName` [image: This API has not been standardized.]: Optional. The value for the `fileName` property on the created `Error` object. Defaults to the name of the file containing the code that called the `Error()` constructor.
- `lineNumber` [image: This API has not been standardized.]:  Optional. The value for the `lineNumber` property on the created `Error` object. Defaults to the line number containing the `Error()` constructor invocation.

Those big yellow warnings have the title "This API has not been standardized." (which you can see on hover).  If you look at the [compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error#Browser_compatibility) at the bottom of the documentation, it currently says that only Firefox supports those parameters.  Other browsers and node don't.

So I guess the reason TypeScript doesn't include them in its [standard library definition for the `Error` constructor](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.2.2/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L968-L972) is because it's not guaranteed to work in all JavaScript environments.

---

Now if you're **certain** that the environment in which you will run your emitted JS code does support those parameters (i.e., if you are only going to run the code in Firefox), you can use [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation) in your own TypeScript code to add the appropriate signature:

```
// assuming your code is in a module, so using global augmentation here
declare global {
  interface ErrorConstructor {
    new(message?: string, fileName?: string, lineNumber?: number): Error;
  }
}
```

And then the compiler will not warn you:

```
export const iAmInAModule = true;
throw new Error("Badness happened", "badthing.js", 123); // no compiler warning now
```

as you wanted.

---

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: I completely understand your initial remarks and I only used the Error constructor as an example for this type of use case. The second part of your feedback perfectly explains how to solve the problem. Thank you!